# Firefox - How save all open images in different tabs?

Tags: firefox, download, automation

I have a window of firefox, with 150 tabs opened, each one having one picture.
The only content of the page is the picture (but the link of the page sometimes is .php, not a exactly picture mimetype)

So, is there a way that automatize this work and save all opened images on that tabs?

Firefox: 3.5.9 (Ubuntu-9.10 Linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but after trying a ... well, a fair amount of various extensions for things like that I settled for something more simple. It's called ***Show the Image*** (I currently have 0.7 version installed; an update may have been released in the meantime), a firefox extension that gives you the largest image on the page after Ctrl-Q. So if you've got fast fingers, combined with Ctrl-W for closing tabs, and Ctrl-S/Enter ... it enables you to go through a lot of tabs just saving images (also handles the .php problem; since after Ctrl-Q you'll get the .jpg/.gif or the appropriate).

As I said, I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but if you're interested, give it a try. Just might work for ya.

edit: oh, yeah ... forgot. Works nicely with ***SnapLinks*** extension (rather popular one) which enables you to open several links (images) simultaneously in different tabs.

Comment: Ya, I did something like that now. Went through pages, and saving each one by hand. Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If the images came from a single image gallery, you can automate this process through an addon called DownloadThemAll - This won't help if you only have the actual tabs and no gallery, however.

Comment: Yeah, but the images came from different places. But thank you for the answer. I know DownThemAll, and use it so much. It's a nice extension.

Answer (score 0):

i use tab image saver and it download image from all tab you have at once and have more option such as

-Select from active tab, tabs to the left/right of current tab, or all tabs.
-Cancel running operations
-Set minimum image size in pixels
-Option to only save tabs with images, ignoring tabs with webpages
-Filenames renamed automatically
-Display badge on icon with runtime information and count of downloads
-Close tabs after saving

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).